# Не создается бинарное дерево

Tags: java, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

В строке присвоения значения root.data возникает ошибка NullPointerExeption, не могу понять почему.
Метод makeTree должен создавать дерево

```
private static Node root;

public static void makeTree(String input) {

    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = input.charAt(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

        if (root == null && (input.charAt(i) == '*' || input.charAt(i) == '/' || input.charAt(i) == '%')) {

            root.data = input.charAt(i);
            root.leftChild.data = input.charAt(i - 2);
            root.rightChild.data = input.charAt(i - 1);
            removeCharAt(input, i);
            removeCharAt(input, i - 1);
            removeCharAt(input, i - 1);

        }

        if (input.charAt(i) == '*' || input.charAt(i) == '/' || input.charAt(i) == '%') {

            root.rightChild = root;
            root.data = input.charAt(i);
            root.leftChild.data = input.charAt(i - 1);
            removeCharAt(input, i);
            removeCharAt(input, i - 1);

        }

        if (input.charAt(i) == '+' || input.charAt(i) == '-') {

            root.rightChild.data = root.data;
            root.data = input.charAt(i);
            root.leftChild.data = input.charAt(0);
            removeCharAt(input, i);
            removeCharAt(input, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Класс Node

```
public class Node {

int data;
Node leftChild;
Node rightChild;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if (root == null && (input.charAt(i) == '*' || input.charAt(i) == '/' || input.charAt(i) == '%')) {

        root.data = input.charAt(i);
```

Вы же сами сначала проверяете root на null, а потом сразу же обращаетесь к полю этого самого root. Не хватает инициализации объекта, что-то вроде root = new Node().